# How to replace re-CAPTCHA code with the invisible re-CAPTCHA code on this particular form

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

Thank you for helping in advance, my mission is to replace the standard Google re-CAPTCHA with the relatively new invisible re-CAPTCHA on this very form while keeping in tact all the messages on a successful/or not

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sib_prefix = 'sib';
    var sib_dateformat = 'mm-dd-yyyy';
</script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=myCallBack&render=explicit&hl=en"></script>

<script>
    var verifyCallback = function(response) {
        if(response.length > 0) {
            $(".captcha > div.row > div.message_area").remove();
        }
    };

    var myCallBack = function() {
        //Render the recaptcha1 on the element with ID "recaptcha1"
        if($('.captcha > div.row > div#gcaptcha').length > 0) {
            var captcha = grecaptcha.render('gcaptcha', {
              'sitekey' : '6LfF6yMUAAAAAFtaUVQkV8p-fG4ZDCxnrKQMiB1b',
              'theme' : 'light',
              'callback' : verifyCallback,
            });
        }
    };
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://my.sendinblue.com/public/theme/version4/assets/js/src/subscribe-validate.js?v=1500542426'></script>
```

```html
<!-- SendinBlue Signup Form HTML Code --><head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>
<style>
   
</style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://my.sendinblue.com/public/theme/version4/assets/styles/style.css" />
<div id="sib_embed_signup" style="padding: 10px;">
    <div class="forms-builder-wrapper" style="position:relative;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;">
                <input type="hidden" id="sib_embed_signup_lang" value="en">
        <input type="hidden" id="sib_embed_invalid_email_message" value="That email address is not valid. Please try again.">
     <input type="hidden" name="primary_type" id="primary_type" value="email">
        <div id="sib_loading_gif_area" style="position: absolute;z-index: 9999;display: none;">
          <img src="https://my.sendinblue.com/public/theme/version4/assets/images/loader_sblue.gif" style="display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;position: relative;top: 40%;">
        </div>
                <form class="description" id="theform" name="theform" action="https://my.sendinblue.com/users/subscribeembed/js_id/2scv0/id/6" onsubmit="return false;">
            <input type="hidden" name="js_id" id="js_id" value="2scv0"><input type="hidden" name="listid" id="listid" value="14"><input type="hidden" name="from_url" id="from_url" value="yes"><input type="hidden" name="hdn_email_txt" id="hdn_email_txt" value="">
                        <div class="sib-container rounded">
                
               <input type="hidden" name="req_hid" id="req_hid" value="~Captcha" style="font-size: 13px;">
               <div class="header" style="padding:0 20px;">
                </div>
                  
                    <div class="view-messages" style=" margin:5px 0;"> </div>
                        <!-- an email as primary -->
            <div class="primary-group email-group forms-builder-group ui-sortable" style="">
                <div class="row mandatory-email" style="padding: 10px 20px; position: relative; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(52, 52, 52); font-size: 17px;">
                    <div class="lbl-tinyltr"  style="clear: both; float: none; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">Enter your email address to subscribe. <red style="color:#ff0000;">*</red></div>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" style="padding: 10px 4px; width: 90%; min-width: auto;">
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                    <div class="hidden-btns">
                        <a class="btn move" href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrows"></i></a><br>
                        <!--<a class="btn btn-danger delete"  href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-inverse"></i></a>-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
                                        <div class="captcha forms-builder-group"><div class="row" style="font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(52, 52, 52); font-size: 17px; padding: 10px 20px;"><div id="gcaptcha" style="transform: scale(1); margin-left: 0px;"></div></div></div>
                         
            <!-- end of primary -->
                         <div class="byline" style="font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(52, 52, 52); font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; display: block;">
                         <button class="button editable " type="submit" data-editfield="subscribe"  style="font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background: rgb(5, 5, 5); display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap; min-height: 40px; margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px; padding: 0px 22px; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; cursor: pointer; border: 0px; border-radius: 4px; vertical-align: top; height: auto; line-height: 150%;">Subscribe</button></div>
                         <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- End : SendinBlue Signup Form HTML Code -->
```

submission.

This is the documentation that Google provides https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible

If someone knows how to fix this, please show me how.

Also note, that I added Stackoverflow.com in the list of sites that my captcha sitekey can work on.

Much appreciation

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sib_prefix = 'sib';
    var sib_dateformat = 'mm-dd-yyyy';
</script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=myCallBack&render=explicit&hl=en"></script>

<script>
    var verifyCallback = function(response) {
        if(response.length > 0) {
            $(".captcha > div.row > div.message_area").remove();
        }
    };

    var myCallBack = function() {
        //Render the recaptcha1 on the element with ID "recaptcha1"
        if($('.captcha > div.row > div#gcaptcha').length > 0) {
            var captcha = grecaptcha.render('gcaptcha', {
              'sitekey' : '6LfF6yMUAAAAAFtaUVQkV8p-fG4ZDCxnrKQMiB1b',
              'theme' : 'light',
              'callback' : verifyCallback,
            });
        }
    };
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://my.sendinblue.com/public/theme/version4/assets/js/src/subscribe-validate.js?v=1500542426'></script>
```

```html
<!-- SendinBlue Signup Form HTML Code --><head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>
<style>
    div#sib_embed_signup .needsfilled input {border-color: #B94A48 !important; color: #B94A48 !important;}
    div#sib_embed_signup .needsfilled {color: #B94A48 !important;}
    div#sib_embed_signup input[type="text"] {border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;border-radius: 4px;-moz-border-radius: 4px;-webkit-border-radius: 4px;}
    div#sib_embed_signup div.message_area {position: relative;padding: 10px 30px 10px 10px; margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;font-size:14px; border-radius: 5px;-webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px;box-sizing: border-box;}
    div#sib_embed_signup div.message_area button.close {position: absolute;right: 8px;top: 8px;color: inherit;background: 0 0;border: 0;padding: 0px;-webkit-appearance: none;cursor: pointer;font-weight: bold;font-size: 14px;}
    .tipicon{cursor: pointer;padding: 3px 7px;font-size: 12px;font-weight: bold;line-height: 1.2;color: #fff;text-align: center;vertical-align: baseline;background-color: #999;border-radius: 10px;text-decoration: none;}
    .tooltip{display: inline;position: absolute;left: 97%;}
    .tooltip:hover:after{background: #333;background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);border-radius: 5px;color: #fff;content: attr(data-title);right: -2px;bottom: 26px;padding: 5px 15px;position: absolute;z-index: 98;width: 220px;}
    .tooltip_small:hover:after{padding: 5px 5px; width: 150px;}
    .tooltip:hover:before{border: solid;border-color: #333 transparent;border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;bottom: 20px;content: "";left: 1px;position: absolute;z-index: 99;}
    .sib-dropdown-menu.flag-icon {display: none;height: 100px;overflow-x: hidden;min-width: 160px;font-size: 13px;list-style: none;padding-left:14px;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);background: white;border-radius: 4px;margin-top:10px;}
    .sib-dropdown-menu.flag-icon li a{display: block;white-space: nowrap;text-decoration: none;color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);box-shadow: none;}
    .sms_field .country-block{margin-right: 3px !important;float: left;width:56px;}
    .icon-arrow{display: inline-block;width:0px;height: 0px;margin-left:2px;margin-top:5px;border-top:4px dashed;border-right:4px solid transparent;border-left:4px solid transparent;vertical-align: text-top;}
    .sib-dropdown-toggle.country-flg{display: inline-block;font-size: 13px;}
    body {background-Image: url('');}
body {background-color: #ffffff;}
div#sib_embed_signup .sib-container {background: rgba(255,255,255,1);}
div#sib_embed_signup .sib-container h1 {font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}
div#sib_embed_signup h1.title {font-size: 45px;}
div#sib_embed_signup .sib-container .forms-builder-footer, div#sib_embed_signup .sib-container .description, div#sib_embed_signup .sib-container .fake-label, div#sib_embed_signup .sib-container .row, div#sib_embed_signup .sib-container #company-name{font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}
div#sib_embed_signup .forms-builder-footer,div#sib_embed_signup div.description,div#sib_embed_signup .fake-label,div#sib_embed_signup .row  {font-size: 17px;}
div#sib_embed_signup .sib-container .button {font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}
div#sib_embed_signup .button{font-size: 14px;}
div#sib_embed_signup input {font-size: 13px;}
div#sib_embed_signup .sib-containter h1 {color: #232323;}
div#sib_embed_signup .sib-container {color: #343434;}
div#sib_embed_signup .sib-container .button{color: #ffffff;}
div#sib_embed_signup .sib-container .button{background: #0f2b5d;}
div#sib_embed_signup .forms-builder-wrapper{ max-width: 540px;}
div#sib_embed_signup .sib-container{ padding: 40px 20px 20px;}
div#sib_embed_signup .header{ padding: 0 20px;}
div#sib_embed_signup h1.title{ lineHeight: 50px;}
div#sib_embed_signup h3.company-name{ lineHeight: 35px;}
div#sib_embed_signup div.description{ padding: 0 20px 15px;}
div#sib_embed_signup div.row{ padding:10px 20px; }
div#sib_embed_signup input[type=text]{ padding: 10px 4px;width:100% !important;box-sizing: border-box;}
</style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://my.sendinblue.com/public/theme/version4/assets/styles/style.css" />
<div id="sib_embed_signup" style="padding: 10px;">
    <div class="forms-builder-wrapper" style="position:relative;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;">
                <input type="hidden" id="sib_embed_signup_lang" value="en">
        <input type="hidden" id="sib_embed_invalid_email_message" value="That email address is not valid. Please try again.">
        <input type="hidden" name="primary_type" id="primary_type" value="email">
        <div id="sib_loading_gif_area" style="position: absolute;z-index: 9999;display: none;">
          <img src="https://my.sendinblue.com/public/theme/version4/assets/images/loader_sblue.gif" style="display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;position: relative;top: 40%;">
        </div>
                <form class="description" id="theform" name="theform" action="https://my.sendinblue.com/users/subscribeembed/js_id/2scv0/id/1" onsubmit="return false;">
            <input type="hidden" name="js_id" id="js_id" value="2scv0"><input type="hidden" name="listid" id="listid" value="2"><input type="hidden" name="from_url" id="from_url" value="yes"><input type="hidden" name="hdn_email_txt" id="hdn_email_txt" value="">
                        <div class="sib-container rounded">
                
               <input type="hidden" name="req_hid" id="req_hid" value="~Captcha" style="font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
               <div class="header" style="padding: 0px 20px;">
                    <h1 class="title editable" data-editfield="newsletter_name"  style="font-weight: normal; text-align: left; font-size: 45px; margin-bottom: 2px; padding: 0px; margin-top: 0px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(35, 35, 35); display: none;">My Newsletter</h1>
            <h3 id="company-name"  style="font-weight: normal; text-align: left; font-size: 25px; margin-bottom: 12px; padding: 0px; margin-top: 0px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(52, 52, 52); display: none;">By</h3>
                </div>
                    <div class="description editable" data-editfield="newsletter_description"  style="padding: 0px 20px 15px; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(52, 52, 52); font-size: 17px; display: none;">What type of content do you plan to share with your subscribers? </div>
                    <div class="view-messages" style=" margin:5px 0;"> </div>
                        <!-- an email as primary -->
            <div class="primary-group email-group forms-builder-group ui-sortable" style="">
                <div class="row mandatory-email" style="padding: 10px 20px; position: relative; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(52, 52, 52); font-size: 17px;">
                    <div class="lbl-tinyltr"  style="clear: both; float: none; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">Enter your email address to subscribe. <red style="color:#ff0000;">*</red></div>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" style="padding: 10px 4px; width: 90%; min-width: auto;">
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                    <div class="hidden-btns">
                        <a class="btn move" href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrows"></i></a><br>
                        <!--<a class="btn btn-danger delete"  href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-inverse"></i></a>-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
                                        <div class="captcha forms-builder-group" style="display: block;"><div class="row" style="font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(52, 52, 52); font-size: 17px; padding: 10px 20px;"><div id="gcaptcha" style="transform: scale(1); margin-left: 0px;"></div></div></div>
                         
            <!-- end of primary -->
                         <div class="byline" style="font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(52, 52, 52); font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; display: block;">
                         <button class="button editable " type="submit" data-editfield="subscribe"  style="font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background: rgb(15, 43, 93); display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap; min-height: 40px; margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px; padding: 0px 10px; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; cursor: pointer; border: 0px; border-radius: 4px; vertical-align: top; height: auto; line-height: 150%;">Subscribe</button></div>
                         <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- End : SendinBlue Signup Form HTML Code -->
```

Comment: It'd be really nice if you could reduce the example down to a [mcve].

Comment: I will do my best, thank you for the feedback!

Comment: @evolutionxbox I minimized it as much as I am able to